# Algorithm to find best combination in multi-dimensional array based on certain criteria

Tags: algorithm, multidimensional-array, combinations

I am looking for an algorithm to work out the best combination based on criteria (Best == use the most cells possible and if possible use all cells). The source is always a multi-dimensional array and only consists of 2 different elements. The goal is to use all the elements in the array and elements can only be used once.

As an example :

Input (Multi-Dimensional array) :

```
AAAAA
ABBBA
AAAAA
```

Where the first items position is 0,0

Criteria :

1. Every combination must contain at least one A and at least one B.
2. The maximum number of cells per combination allowed is 6.

The solution for this example is :

Three different combinations that uses every cell from input and does not exceed the maximum number of cells per combination that is 6

```
AA    A    AA
AB    B    BA
AA    A    AA
```

The first combination is between rows 0,2 and columns 0,1

The second combination is between rows 0,2 and columns 2,2

The third combination is between rows 0,2 and columns 3,4

A more real life example would be

```
ABBBAAA
BBBBABB
AABAABA
ABBABBB
AAAAAAB
AAAAAAB
```

Criteria :

1. Every combination must contain at least one A and at least one B.
2. The maximum number of cells per combination allowed is 5.

Comment: What are combinations? Do they have to be rectangular (or the higher dimensional equivalent)? I guess they need to be at least connected? At what means "best"?

Comment: Yes they need to be connected. And yes they must also be rectangular.

Comment: We still don't know what you consider "best", but studying this may help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%27s_Algorithm_X

Comment: After a bit of research on Knuth and his work on Algorithm X, I do not think it is applicable in this scenario

Comment: What is you expected output on input where all element are `A` except 0,0 and `n-1,n-1` which are `B`?

Comment: Not exactly. What is expected is to split the input into rectangles that contain at least the minimum amount of each element in the input ( in this case A,B)